# MySql HasRows alway return true

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I has a problem in my code:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cnstr))
{
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand checkuser = new MySqlCommand("select * from table1 where UserID='A00001' and FHDate < '" + DateTime.Now + "'",conn);
    MySqlDataReader chk = checkuser.ExecuteReader();
    if (chk.HasRows)
    {  .......  }
```

When FHDate='2016-01-17' chk.HasRows return true is this right answer,
but FHDate='2016-01-19' chk.HasRows still return true. I can find where I did wrong?

Please help.

Comment: That code is crying to get SQL injected...

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: so are you saying the reason why chk.HasRows always returns true is due to the possibility of SQL Injection???

Comment: try to change your query to *select * from table1 where UserID = 'A00001' and FHDate < getdate()*, and then: *if (chk.Read() && chk.HasRows)*

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your `FHDate` column is some Datetime typed but you supply your `DateTime` value as a `string`, it *still* returns true for string comparison.

Add this `DateTime.Now` value with a [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) and supply it's parameter type with `MySqlDbType` as Datetime and it should be okey *if* everything is okey other than that.

```
MySqlCommand checkuser = new MySqlCommand("select * from table1 where UserID='A00001' and FHDate < @date", conn);
checkuser.Parameters.Add("@date", MySqlDbType.Datetime).Value = DateTime.Now;
...
```

Also use `using` statement to dispose your command and reader as you did for your connection.

Comment: I amended my code to this :
MySqlCommand checkuser = new MySqlCommand("select FHDate from fahuiuser where UserID='A00001' and fhdate < @fhdate order by fhdate desc limit 1", conn);
checkuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fhdate", DateTime.Now);

it still return true

Comment: @Leec.c. Have you ever this query in your database manager? It doesn't return any row in there?

Comment: @Leec.c. What do you mean by right results? "No data" you mean?

Comment: '2016-01-17' < '2016-01-18' will list out data, ;2016-01-19'<'2016-01-18' no data

Comment: @Leec.c. You are not comparing your values in WHERE clause, you are filtering your results where condition (which is `FHDate < DateTime.Now`) is `true` How did you supply this `2016-01-19` for example? Is it like `DateTime.Date.AddDays(1)` or something? Your logic is some kind of wrong in my opinion.